# What's the Big-O of T(n)=Constant?

Tags: algorithm, big-o, time-complexity, code-analysis

Would it be O(Constant)?
Example:
T(n) = 10
Would be correct to say that the big-o is O(10)?

Comment: @EugeneSh., thanks, what about T(n)=(n^n), would it be O(n^n)?

Comment: Yes. But this is a horrible time complexity :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We usually write it as O(1) since constant factors aren't relevant.

Of course a zero constant is mathematically quite distinct. For our practical purposes, nothing takes no time in all cases, unless we aren't doing it. And if we aren't doing it, we probably don't care.

Comment: But is it considered wrong saying that T(n) = 10 Big-O is O(10)?

Comment: Not really. But it is like writing `1125/2250` instead of `1/2`.

Comment: It's not wrong, no, it's just not simplified. The sets of functions in O(1) and O(10) are the same sets.